# Does there exist a polynomial $P(x,y)$ which detects all non-squares?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

**Problem.** Does there exist a two-variable polynomial $P(x, y)$ with integer coefficients such that a positive integer $n$ is **not** a perfect square *if and only if* there is a pair $(x, y)$ of positive integers such that $P(x, y)=n$?

**Context.** The answer is positive for polynomials in 3 variables! This appeared as a problem in USA Team Selection Test in 2013. It turns out that the polynomial $P(x, y, z)=z^2\cdot (x^2-zy^2-1)^2+z$  enjoys the following property: a positive integer $n$ is a not a perfect square if and only if $P(x, y, z)=n$ has a solution in positive integers $(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{N}^{3}$. This construction works nicely due to Pell's equation. If $n$ is not a perfect square, then Pell's equation $x^2-ny^2=1$ has a solution in positive integers $(x_0, y_0)$, and so we get $P(x_0, y_0, n) = n$. Conversely, if $P(x, y, z)=n$, then one can show that $n$ cannot be a perfect square because $n=z^2(x^2-zy^2-1)^2+z$ can be squeezed between two consecutive perfect squares:
$$
 (z(x^2-zy^2-1))^2 < n < (z(|x^2-zy^2-1|+1)^2
$$

**Remark.** It is clear that there is no single-variable polynomial $P(x)$ which could achieve the desired property. Indeed, there are arbitrary number of consecutive non-squares, and a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n>1$ cannot output a consecutive list of $n+1$ numbers. This last claim itself is a nice problem; for a solution, see Example 2.24 in page 11 of *Number Theory: Concepts and Problems* by Andreescu, Dospinescu and Mushkarov.

Comment: A possibly helpful note: This can be done with two very similar polynomials $P_1(x,y)=(x+y-1)^2+y$ and $P_2(x,y)=(x+y-1)^2+(x+y-1)+y$. These two polynomials have disjoint images, with $\operatorname{Im}(P_1)\cup \operatorname{Im}(P_2)$ representing all non-squares: the image of $P_1$ is the union of the intervals $[n^2+1,n^2+n]$ for each $n\geq 1$, while the image of $P_2$ is the union of the intervals $[n^2+n+1,n^2+2n]$ for each $n\geq 1$. (This can be used to construct a $3$-variable polynomial
$$P(x,y,z)=\big(1-(z-1)(z-2)\big)\big((x+y-1)^2+(z-1)(x+y-1)+y\big)$$
with the desired property.

Comment: I cannot answer the above question but I can say that every odd square can be represented by $P(x,y)=(x+y)^2=x^2 + 2xy +y^2$ with $xy=2T_n$ with $T_n$ twice a triangular number and also $y=x+1$. Ex: $81=9^2=(4+5)^2=4^2 + 2*4*5 + 5^2$. Example of P(x,y) for a non-square: $73=(72/2 + 74/2)=1+2*18+6^2$. Note that $18$ is not twice a triangular number. This means than non-squares can be represented by $P(x,y)$ but $x$ and $y$ will necessarily differ by more than $1$. If $(N-1)/2$ is odd, the number can never be a square. Ex $71$ with $(71-1)/2=35$ or $91$ with $(91-1)/2=45$.

Comment: In fact, the polynomial $P=p*q=[(p-1)/2 + (p+1)/2]*[(q-1)/2 + (q+1)/2]$ can represent non-squares and non-primes. Example: $91=7*13=(3+4)*(6+7)=3*6 +3*7 +4*6 + 4*7$ with $(91-1)/2=3*7 + 4*6=45$ and $(91+1)/2=3*6 + 4*7=46$.

Comment: Interesting problem, you might want to consider asking on MathOverflow as it was not resolved here even after bounty.

Comment: @Sil Great suggestion! Just posted the problem on MathOverFlow [at this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432878/does-there-exist-a-polynomial-which-detects-all-non-squares).